# Visual Studio Code: Cannot find module - app.vue

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, vetur

For the following line of code in `App.vue`

```
import TestComponent from '@/mytest/components/TestComponent.vue'
```

Vscode, specifically the vetur plugin, gives the error `cannot find module @/mytest/components/TestComponent.vue`

I checked my tsconfig.json file and my alias is correct set up as follows:

```
 "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
```

the path to my component is: `src/mytest/components/TestComponent.vue`

The code compiles and runs just fine, it's Vscode giving me these errors.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Did you paste that code verbatim from your code?  If so,

```
import TestComponent from '@/mytest/components/TestComponent.vue` <---
```

Your last single quote is a back quote.